# Here API - Remove Map

Tags: javascript, here-api

Im working on an App which retrieves the Users Location via Geolocation-API. 
When the user clicks on a button a "HERE-API" Map gets initialized and the user has the option to drag a marker to the exact postition if it isn't already. 
When he clicks on the Abort-Button i want to "destroy" or remove the entire Map since i dont want it to be displayed on the screen all the time. Just when the user clicks the Button which retrieves the Location and displays the Map.

I did alot of research on StackOverflow and the Official Documentation but i haven't found any Information on how to approach this.

Can someone please help me.

```
$("#addLocation").on('click', function()
{
    $("#mapContainer").fadeIn();

    function addDraggableMarker(map, behavior)
    {
        var svgMarkup = `<svg width="40" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><title>background</title><rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="42" width="42" y="-1" x="-1"/></g><g><title>Layer 1</title><path stroke="null" fill="#046f47" id="svg_1" d="m20,0.701143a15.19595,15.19595 0 0 0 -15.19595,15.19595c0,10.257267 13.296457,21.844179 13.96128,22.338047l1.234671,1.063717l1.234671,-1.063717c0.664823,-0.493868 13.96128,-12.080781 13.96128,-22.338047a15.19595,15.19595 0 0 0 -15.19595,-15.19595zm0,22.793926a7.597975,7.597975 0 1 1 7.597975,-7.597975a7.597975,7.597975 0 0 1 -7.597975,7.597975z"/><circle stroke="null" fill="#046f47" id="svg_2" r="3.938806" cy="16.03728" cx="19.999999"/></g></svg>`;

        var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup);
        var coords = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        };
        var marker = new H.map.Marker(
            coords, {
                icon: icon
            }, {
                volatility: true
            }
        );

        // Ensure that the marker can receive drag events
        marker.draggable = true;
        map.addObject(marker);

        // disable the default draggability of the underlying map and calculate the offset between mouse and target's position when starting to drag a marker object:
        map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target,
                pointer = ev.currentPointer;
            if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
                var targetPosition = map.geoToScreen(target.getGeometry());
                target['offset'] = new H.math.Point(pointer.viewportX - targetPosition.x, pointer.viewportY - targetPosition.y);
                behavior.disable();
            }
        }, false);

        // re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map when dragging has completed
        map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
                behavior.enable();
            }
        }, false);

        // Listen to the drag event and move the position of the marker as necessary
        map.addEventListener('drag', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target,
                pointer = ev.currentPointer;
            if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
                target.setGeometry(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX - target['offset'].x, pointer.viewportY - target['offset'].y));
            }
        }, false);
    }

    //Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'MY-API-KEY'
    });

    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    //Step 2: initialize a map
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
            center: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            },
            zoom: 16,
            pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
        });

    // add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

    //Step 3: make the map interactive - MapEvents enables the event system - Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Step 4: Create the default UI:
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, "de-DE");

    // Add the click event listener.
    addDraggableMarker(map, behavior);
});




$('#mapButtonAbort').on('click', function() {

  // Something like map.destroy()  

});
```

Comment: I did a little workaround just in case someone stumbles across this post looking for a solution to this "issue" aswell. On the beginning of the page i define a "mapInit" variable which is set to false. Now when the user closes the map by either clicking "Save Position" or "Abort" i simply fadeOut the Map and set the "mapInit" variable to true. When the 'addLocation' Button is clicked i simply check if the "mapInit" Variable is set to false. If so a new map gets initialized. Otherwise i simply fadeIn the map again.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, you can also remove the DOM element when the user click on the "Hide" button and vice-versa, onAttach, Detach callbacks can also be created, please reference for that.. 
developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/best-practices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

- On the beginning of the page is was a "mapInit" variable defined which is set to false. Now when the user closes the map by either clicking "Save Position" or "Abort" it  simply fadeOut the Map and set the "mapInit" variable to true. As a workaround: when the 'addLocation' Button is clicked it simply check if the "mapInit" Variable is set to false. If so a new map gets initialized. Otherwise i simply fadeIn the map again.
- Another possibility is to remove the DOM element when the user click on the "Hide" button and vice-versa, onAttach, Detach callbacks can also be created, please reference for that.. developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/best-practices.html